# Hash merge and reorder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I want 2 hashes to be merged and provided to me as given below in 'Expected result' section.
Any ideas ?

Example data:

```
list1 = { '1' => [item1] }
list2 = { '1' => [item2], '2' => [item3]}
```

Expected result

```
{ 
  '1' => {:from_list1 => [item1], :from_list2 => [item2]},
  '2' => {:from_list2 => [item3]}
}
```

Note : This is almost an update of my other question in [Best way to combine 2 hashes in this order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12348105/best-way-to-combine-2-hashes-in-this-order)

Comment: This should be relatively straightforward; what have you tried so far?

Comment: Your expected result is not a valid Ruby object.

Comment: why is in not a valid ruby object ? It is a hash. and the values of the hash are also hashes. Is that a wrong ruby object ? Ruby accepted it with no issues. item1, item2, etc are objects of some class i have defined.

Comment: @DivyaBhargov Do not tell a lie. It was not a hash until rogal111 edited the question. Ruby could definitely not have accepted it in the form before it was edited by rogal111.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nested [inject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
list1={'1'=>['item1'],'3'=>['item4']}
list2={"1"=>["item2"], "2"=>["item3"]} 

list2.inject(list1.inject({}) { |c, (k, v)| 
   c[k]=(list2.has_key?(k) ? {:from_list1=>v,:from_list2=>list2[k]} : {:from_list1=>v}) 
   c
   }) { |c, (k, v)| 
      c[k]||={:from_list2=>v}
      c
}

#result:
{"1"=>{:from_list1=>["item1"], :from_list2=>["item2"]}, "3"=>{:from_list1=>["item4"]}, "2"=>{:from_list2=>["item3"]}}
```

Comment: No .. that does not work when one of the lists does not have a the key. In the above example, it will only return {"1"=>{:from_list1=>[item1], :from_list2=>[item2]}, "2"=>[item3]} . See the 2nd key has an array instead of hash